# retrieve json file from server

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to get a json file from my server. Until now, always I need a json file, it was got by ajax and a php file in server creates the json file.

Not I have a json file (X.json) with this structure:

```
{
"zona": [
    {
        "zona1": [
            {
                "lon": "a",
                "lat": "b"
            },
            {
                "lon": "aa",
                "lat": "bb"
            },
            {
                "lon": "aaa",
                "lat": "bbb"
            },
            {
                "lon": "aaaa",
                "lat": "bbbb"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "zona2": [
            {
                "lon": "c",
                "lat": "d"
            },
            {
                "lon": "cc",
                "lat": "dd"
            },
            {
                "lon": "ccc",
                "lat": "ddd"
            },
            {
                "lon": "cccc",
                "lat": "dddd"
            },
            {
                "lon": "ccccc",
                "lat": "ddddd"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

And when I try the same way to get the file, I didn't get anything. I think maybe it is possible to add the file when I load the webpage like a javascript file. Or maybe with jsonp but I trid and also I got bad answer.

As json try, I used:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'localhost/open/listaPuntosZona.json',
        type: 'GET',
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallbackfunction",
        error: function () {
            alert("Error in Jsonp");
        }
    });

function jsonpCallbackfunction(responseData) {
alert(responseData);    

}
```

Also I wrapped json file with: callback( jsonfile code)

And also, this other two tries:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'localhost/open/listaPuntosZona.json', 
  type: 'get', 
  error: function(data){ }, 
  complete: function(data){ 

    data=jQuery.parseJSON(data); //do something with data

    alert(data.zona.zona1.length);
  }
});



$.getJSON('localhost/open/listaPuntosZona.json',function(jsonData){
    alert("hola");
    alert(jsonData);
});
```

I am using lampp to test the webpage.

Do I have to change something? I used jsonp in past but don't know what I am doing wrong now.

Comment: if you go at localhost/open/listaPuntosZona.json in your brawser does it show the correct JSON?

Comment: also try using success: instead of complete:

Comment: I tried with success and complete, same result.
If I write the url in my browser it shows me the json file. I tested it with a json checker and it is correct I think

Comment: have you tried just echoing the JSON form your PHP?

Comment: let's say you have a SQLDB, you can perform your selects and set up an array with your retrived datas, then echo json_encode(yourArray). Or you can have your server generate XML documents and save them, then you open them in your php, parse them and echo json_encode(yourXML)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try using `$.getJSON()` instead of plain $.ajax(). it will solve many problems right off the bat.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Secondly, make sure your json file is formatted perfectly, without any loose characters and strange whitespaces.

Also try to chain an error handler to your ajax call. available in the getJSON documentation above.

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("example.json").error(function() { alert("error"); });
// this is according to documentation, i cannot currently test this to work, sorry about that.
```

Comment: I tried with no whitespaces, same result. And Using your error function, I got: error in promt window.

Comment: you are right, that was only an example, try this instead: `.error(function(rta,rtb,rtc) { console.log(rta,rtb,rtc); });` as i am not sure what this function returns. then open your developer console in Firefox or Chrome using F12 and check the console tab.

Comment: I already tried, this is the output: XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost/open/listaPuntosZona.json. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Object "error" ""

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but in case someone else has this issue like I did, here is how I was able to fix it...

Add the following line to the **.htaccess** file...

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```